# Is it possible to transform chemical energy in electrical energy by modifying the equilibrium constant?

Tags: electricity, electrochemistry

Considering a Daniell cell, is it possible to create endlessly electrical energy by using atmospheric temperature (for example) variations to modify the reaction's equilibrium constant ? I apologize if this question is trivial.

Comment: ""endlessly "" For any electron in the circuit You have to react half a Zinc atom and a quarter of a MnO2. Temperature can alter the voltage of the cell, but never the amount of charge it gives off. And for Voltage: there is nothing "free" in that, thermodynamics works precisely in electrochemistry.

Comment: I'll try to reformulate... My point is: if the system is put permanently under significant variations of temperature (positive and negative), will it be permanently reacting due to the modification of the equilibrium constant ?

Comment: Bastien, google for "Nernst Equation". For a Danielle You need one term according to Nernst for the Kathode and another one for the Anode. But be aware: this is only euilibrium condition without any current!